# How to apply a theme on a page in the root directory in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My custom page is at `http://localhost/project/custom.php`.

I want to apply the default theme on it.

How can I do that?

Comment: tell me your wordpress code inside project directory

Comment: i want some custom query from that page.i created widget which submit form to that page.And i perform some operation on it.Now i want to style it with default theme if it is possible.

Comment: there is no need that to keep that page outside the wordpress directory and create custom template and write your code in custom template

Comment: but on custom page my post data are not accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

i got it your problem follow those step

1)Make file inside in wordpress/themes/your_theme/customcode.php and put below code in that file

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Code
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

//put your custom code

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

2)Now make page with customcode with wp-admin of wordpress and choose Template Custom Code

3)Update that update after click view see that page link

4)final step where you are using widget give link in from action (where you get from 3 point)

Now do it you won't loose design